# Attribute Error Nonetype has o attribute 'Name'

Tags: python, flask, attributes

new to flask, i'm not so sure why I am getting this name error: 'Nontype' object has no attribute value 'name'.

(PLease ignore: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
")

Here is what it looks like in the console

```
  File "/Users/thomashunt/projects/ct-platform-api/apis/student_api.py", line 448, in put
    return StudentService.student_WorkShadow(submission)
  File "/Users/thomashunt/projects/ct-platform-api/services/students.py", line 234, in student_WorkShadow
    AddressService.set_address_info(submission.student_detail.location_address)
  File "/Users/thomashunt/projects/ct-platform-api/services/addresses.py", line 18, in set_address_info
    address_description = address.address_description(country.name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

services/students

```
@staticmethod 
    def student_WorkShadow(submission: StudentWorkShadowEdit) -> Person:
        repo = PersonData()
        advisor = repo.find_by_email(submission.advisor_email)
        email = submission.email.lower()
        student = repo.find_by_email(email)

        if not student:
            raise RecordNotFoundException('No Record with this email in the database')

        if not advisor:
            raise RecordNotFoundException('No Record with this advisor email in the database')

              # Forced re-write of Address entered by Student
        student.student_detail.location_address = \
            AddressService.set_address_info(submission.student_detail.location_address)


        submission.set_model(student)

        files = StudentService.promote_student_files(advisor, submission.file_ids, student.id)

                # Forced re-write of Address entered by Student


        repo.save(student, advisor.id)
        repo.session.commit()
        student_statement = 'student workshadow details updated'
        reference_fields = [EventItemReferenceField('updated_workshadowDetails', 'Updated workshadow Details'),
                            EventItemReferenceField('form_action', 'confidential_updated')]
        reference_content = [student_statement]

        MessagingActivityService.create_student_event_for_action(student.id, None, student,
                                                                 True,
                                                                 ActionTypes.Student.value.InternalNote,
                                                                 student_statement,
                                                                 reference_fields,
                                                                 reference_content, files, None,
                                                                 None, None, True, True)

        StudentService.re_index(student)
        return student
```

API Endpoints

```
@ns.route('/StudentWorkShadow')
class StudentWorkShadowEndpoint(Resource):
    @SecurityService.requires_system
    @ns.expect(student_workshadow_model, validate=True)
    @ns.marshal_with(student_person_model)
    def put(self):
        logging.info('student workshadow details updated')
        submission = StudentWorkShadowEdit.from_dict(request.json)
        return StudentService.student_WorkShadow(submission)
```

services/address

```
import logging

from models import Address
from resources import AddressEdit
from utility import GoogleUtility
from .data import CountryData


class AddressService:
    @staticmethod
    def set_address_info(address: Address):
        countries = CountryData()
        country = countries.load_country(address.country_code)

        if address.suburb is not None and address.state is not None:
            address.location_description = address.suburb + ', ' + address.state

        address_description = address.address_description(country.name)

        maps_result = GoogleUtility.resolve_coords(address_description)
        try:
            first_result = maps_result[0]
            print(first_result)
            address.latitude = first_result['geometry']['location']['lat']
            address.longitude = first_result['geometry']['location']['lng']
            address.raw_location = first_result
            address.formatted_address = first_result['formatted_address']
        except TypeError:
            print(maps_result.error)
            logging.error(maps_result.error)
        except IndexError:
            logging.error('No result for address resolution')
        return address

    @staticmethod
    def has_address_changed(old_address: Address, new_address: AddressEdit):
        if not old_address and new_address:
            return True
        return not (old_address.line_1 == new_address.line_1
                    and old_address.line_2 == new_address.line_2
                    and old_address.suburb == new_address.suburb
                    and old_address.postcode == new_address.postcode
                    and old_address.country_code == new_address.country_code)
```

country/data outputs:

```
import json

from resources import Country


class CountryData:
    with open('services/data/countries.json') as json_data:
        source = json.load(json_data)
        countries = [Country.from_dict(l) for l in source]

    def load_country(self, country_code: str):
        result = None
        for country in self.countries:
            if country.country_code == country_code:
                result = country
        return result

    def load_state(self, country_code: str, short_title: str):
        result = None
        country = self.load_country(country_code)
        for state in country.states:
            if state.short_title == short_title:
                result = state
        return result

    def list_states(self, country_code: str):
        return self.load_country(country_code).states
```

Comment: Check the output of `countries.load_country(address.country_code)`. My guess is that that it returns `None` (i.e. the load fails for some reason) and assigns it to country. I cannot know for sure without seeing the data.

Comment: @brentertainer I just added the countries.load_contry(address.country_code) data for you in my question if that helps! Thanks alot.

Comment: As I expected, the first line of `load_country` sets `result = None`. If no matching country is found, that is what is returned. You need to be digging into why no matching country is found. That is related to (a) the value of `country_code` passed to that same method and (b) the contents of `'services/data/country.json'`.

Comment: @brentertainer just re read the code and it says in the load_country method the result = country on the 2nd last line before the return result so i'm not sure if it could be that.

Comment: Give me a few moments to clarify some points in an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that the value you pass for `country_code` does not match against any `country.country_code` attribute.

My advice is to put a debug print line in the method like this:

```
class CountryData:

    ...

    def load_country(self, country_code: str):
        result = None
        for country in self.countries:
            if country.country_code == country_code:
                result = country
            print(result, country.country_code) # this line added
        return result

    ...
```

Doing this, you should be able to see if result is ever set to a value other than `None`, and you can observe exactly which country code triggers it. Moreover, this will print all available country codes (one per line). If your `country_code` is not one of these, that is the problem.

Comment: I see what it was, when i was testing my local endpoint data, I didn't send a code which had been matched in the 'services/data/country.json'. model....Silly me!

Comment: @tomhunt (Shilling for myself a bit here.) If this answer solves your problem, you may upvote it and/or select it as the answer using the buttons near the top and to the left of the answer.